# don't show timestamp from each line in zsh shell

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have just installed zsh shel in my terminal.
But with every line I have a timestamp logged (see screenshot)
[image: terminal with timestamp]

I want to get rid of the timestamp.

Can somebody please help me?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Switching to a different theme like "agnoster" can solve the issue you're experiencing.

To do that,

- Open ZSH file (~/.zshrc) and set the theme to agnoster (ZSH_THEME="agnoster")
- Close and quit the current session or save the change (`source ~/.zshrc`)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Powerlevel theme then

Open zsh config file  (~/.zshrc) and set the theme to powerlevel

i.e.

(ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
")

And
Add this line at the bottom of the .zshrc file  --

POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=()